# Full String x-axis labels in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, scatter-plot

In Plotly I am trying to display nice x-axis

The values in `df["yearweek"]` are the weeks of the year: `202101 , 202102, ...`

But in the image the display in odd format

Is there a way to just display as-is, in their raw form ?

```
    fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, 
                    subplot_titles=("Total Job DB Bytes","Average Job DB Bytes","Total Job DB Calls","Average Job DB Calls"))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df["yearweek"], y=df["total_db_size"]), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df["yearweek"], y=df["size_by_jobs"]),  row=1, col=2)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df["yearweek"], y=df["total_db_calls"]),row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df["yearweek"], y=df["calls_by_jobs"]), row=2, col=2)

fig.update_xaxes(tickmode="linear", row=1, col=1)
fig.update_xaxes(tickmode="linear", row=1, col=2)
fig.update_xaxes(tickmode="linear", row=2, col=1)
fig.update_xaxes(tickmode="linear", row=2, col=2)
fig.update_layout(height=800, width=1000, xaxis = {'type' : 'category'}, showlegend=False)
fig.show()
```

[image: Incorrect labels]

EDIT: Here is the full 2x2 subplot layout. Including the type change that vestland suggested below.
This shows the layout only applying to the first plot and the x-axis changing order on that one too.

[image: Layout only applies to first]

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to just display as-is, in their raw form

```
fig.update_layout(xaxis = {'type' : 'category'})
```

[image]

```
# imports 
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

# data
df = pd.DataFrame({'yearweek':[202101 , 202102, 202103],
                   'my_value':[1,2, 4]})

# plotly
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df["yearweek"], y=df["my_value"]))

# plotly x-axis type / format
fig.update_layout(xaxis = {'type' : 'category'})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That almost works, but it only applies to my plot at first 1,1 position and my setup actually has 4 subplots (so plots at 1,2 2,1 & 2,2 a). Plus it reverses the order of the data on the X-axis, so the values on plot 1 are off - Let me post an update above

Comment: @Ro. You're welcome! Regarding `but it only applies to my plot at first 1,1 position...` I'm not inclined to reproduce your complete issue *for you*. So my suggestion focuses only on your core problem for a minimal reproducible example. Which you have not provided. Nor have you provided a proper  sample of your data. So next time, please consider focusing on *one* problem at a time, and provide a fully runnable code snippet with a sample of your data as per StackOverflow guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to vestland's response I was able to work it out. I needed both type='category', categoryorder='category ascending' on every cell like so:

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, 
                    subplot_titles=("Total Job DB Bytes","Average Job DB Bytes","Total Job DB Calls","Average Job DB Calls"))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df["yearweek"], y=df["total_db_size"]), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df["yearweek"], y=df["size_by_jobs"]),  row=1, col=2)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df["yearweek"], y=df["total_db_calls"]),row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df["yearweek"], y=df["calls_by_jobs"]), row=2, col=2)

fig.update_xaxes(tickmode="linear", type='category', categoryorder='category ascending', row=1, col=1)
fig.update_xaxes(tickmode="linear", type='category', categoryorder='category ascending', row=1, col=2)
fig.update_xaxes(tickmode="linear", type='category', categoryorder='category ascending', row=2, col=1)
fig.update_xaxes(tickmode="linear", type='category', categoryorder='category ascending', row=2, col=2)
fig.update_layout(height=800, width=1000, showlegend=False)
fig.show()
```